# IE: Unset window.opener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to check whether a window on my site can be closed with:

```
if (window.opener && window.opener.closed === false) {
```

It is possible for users to reach my site via another window that sets `window.opener`.  I can "reset" `window.opener` when users initially reach my site using: `window.opener = null`.  However, this doesn't work in IE (on the next page, `window.opener` is restored).

Is there a way to "reset" the `window.opener` construct in IE, or another cross-browser solution to my problem in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that's not totally analogous, but will work for my purposes.  I only want to close the window if the opener is from the same domain.

```
if (window.opener.location.hostname.indexOf(window.location.hostname) > -1) {
```

However, IE does not allow you to access `window.opener.location` if the opener is from a different host.  This actually works out quite well:

```
try {
    //snippet above
}
catch (error) { /* no action needed; assume different host */ }
```

Comment: Should be able to refactor the above to `if (window.opener !== window)` to see if its the same reference.

Comment: @MauvisLedford If the user opens a new window from my domain, `window.opener` will not be `window` on the new window, but I'll want it to close.  If the user opens my window from *another* domain, they will also mismatch but I will **not** want it to close.  I think your suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: Touche. `if (window.opener !== null && window.opener !== window)`

Comment: @MauvisLedford that still doesn't solve the exact problem I just said.